# Adding Gradle or Maven to Android projects using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, gradle

I'm trying for 2 days now to add Gradle support for an old Android project using Eclipse (moving to Android Studio is not an option).
I have installed the Buildship plugin and started creating the build.gradle support but I got a problem its not generates alone, so I have to create it by myself and I'm having troubles with how to do it.
I thought of adding Maven instead of Gradle using the m2e plugin. Is there a preference to what should be used with Eclipse and Android - Gradle or Maven? Maybe Maven for now supports Android better than Gradle?

Comment: The support ended for Eclipse. Maybe use a older version? http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html

Comment: I know the support ended for Eclipse but I'm still asking specifically for Eclipse

Comment: Wait this is new.. whats the difference between ending the support they declared 2 years ago when they released that awful AS IDE and this one?

Comment: They stopped the development of the ADT plugin over a year ago. With the recent news they basically implemented all those features (DDMS, Trace Viewer, Network Monitor, and CPU Monitor) into Android Studio. You should really switch to the new IDE otherwise you will run into more issues.

Comment: I'll try it now. In your opinion, is it better to let AS convert the Eclipse project on its own, or should I create a new project and copy paste the source code from the old project?

Comment: Try the official guides. https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html